# Find all indices of an element in a Groovy list

Tags: collections, groovy

I want to find positions of all elements of array with specific value. 
Example:

```
def numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 6, 4, 9, 2];
```

I want to find positions of `4`, here position numbers are 3,7,9

How to find it elegant with nice groovy collections methods?

Answer (score 14):

I have found the solution:

```
println numbers.findIndexValues {
    it == 4;
}
```

Groovy is amazing!!!